# Custom folder inside Sencha'a app folder

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to create a custom folder inside the sencha's app directory. i wanted to have a directory called service (which  just holds all the service related js files) inside app directory. and i wanted to include it in the app.js just like view, controller files.

is it possible to do it? if not what is the best way to do it?

right now i have added all the js files inside the service folder in app.json

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Just create a folder manually inside app folder and instantiate the classes whenever required by calling it with requires : [].

example usage :

```
requires: ['MyApp.service.primeService']
```

include the above line in app.js where MyApp is the application name and service is the custom folder, primeService is the custom js file.

app.js might be as follows :

```
Ext.application({
name: 'MyApp',
appFolder: 'app-demo',   
extend: 'Ext.app.Application',  
requires: ['MyApp.service.primeService'],
launch: function(){
    //code here
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sub)folders in app folder are mapped to class names. You can create subfolder but then class names must match. For example, you want to have `MyClass` in `service` subfolder. Then you must define the class this way:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.service.MyClass', {....})
```

And you must put it in `requires` array in the `Application`:

```
requires:['MyApp.service.MyClass']
```

See [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/class_system) for details